# Can two seperate matrix be divided and saved in a dataframe using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, divide

I have two matrix saved in dataframe.

```
df1                     df2

    0  1  2            0  1  2
0   4  6  2          0 2  3  2
1   2  0  6          1 1  3  2
2   8  2  1          2 4  2  3
```

Is it possible to calculate a third matrix where the elements of df1 gets divided by df2? What is the easiest wayto achieve the same in python? Thank you

```
Desired Output:
   0  1  2
0  2  2  1
1  2  0  3
2  2  0  0.33
```

Comment: `df1.values / df2.values` would be one way to do it and then create a data frame out of that.

Comment: As long as the columns/index indices are the same, pandas will align automatically: `df1/df2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df3 = df1.div(df2)
```

will create a new df after element wise division.